# Magento 2.3 upgrade compilation error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

After I upgraded my magento store from **2.2.5** to **2.3.0** the CSS of the website is not displayed and I get an error when I run this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

The error is:

```
Compilation from source: /htdocs/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
Operation on an invalid type in _typography.less in _utilities.less in _module.less
```

My **system.log** file displays these errors:

```
main.ERROR: Operation on an invalid type in _typography.less in _utilities.less in _module.less
main.CRITICAL: Operation on an invalid type in _typography.less in _utilities.less in _module.less
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks